# Spring 3.2 @RequestParam validation returns HTML instead of JSON

Tags: json, spring

Following block of code is from the spring controller for a REST API

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addExpense", method = RequestMethod.POST,  produces="application/json")
public void createExpense(
            @RequestParam(value="expenseDate" ,required=true)   @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date expenseDate,
            @RequestParam(value="description" , required=true) String description,
            @RequestParam(value="amount" , required=true) Double amount){
// Create Expense
}
```

Config has that entry

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Now the problem is if any of the above validation fails, I get a response that is HTML. havent figured out a way to make it JSON. Anybody?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final - Error report
    </title>
    <style>
      &lt;!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--&gt;
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'description' is not present
    </h1>
    <hr noshade="noshade" size="1"/>
    <p>
      <b>
        type
      </b>
      Status report
    </p>
    <p>
      <b>
        message
      </b>
      <u>
        Required String parameter 'description' is not present
      </u>
    </p>
    <p>
      <b>
        description
      </b>
      <u>
        The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Required String parameter 'description' is not present).
      </u>
    </p>
    <hr noshade="noshade" size="1"/>
    <h3>
      JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final
    </h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What Spring version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is to combine the strengths of a Servlet container and Spring.

Declare an `error-page` in your deployment descriptor

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/400</location>
</error-page>
```

When Spring will fail to find an appropriate request parameter (or for a number of other reasons), it will throw an `Exception` that will be handled `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` by returning a 400 status code. The `error-page` will catch that and will use a `RequestDispatcher` to `forward` to the path in `location`, after setting the error message in the request attributes (among other things).

The `location` can be any exact path for which you will provide a handler method. Something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/400")
public @ResponseBody String handle(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String e = (String) request.getAttribute(javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    System.out.println(e);
    return "400";
}
```

I'm obviously not returning JSON here. Instead, I'm showing you how to get the [error message](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#ERROR_MESSAGE). From that, you can create a POJO and return it to be serialized to JSON with `@ResponseBody` or you can generate the JSON yourself.